# Video.Js Problems Viewing Cross Browser

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I am completely new to VideoJs and media streaming on web pages, so please forgive me if the answer to this is obvious. I uploaded an MP4, OGV and WEBM file to www.sell2trade.com.au. If you view this page you will see that the video on the RHS works in Firefox, has an unsupported error in IE11 and plays the audio only in Chrome!! I downloaded the VideoJS sample and followed it diligently (I think!!) What on earth am I doing wrong!

Thanks for any help as tearing what little hair I have left out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MP4 you're using doesn't appear to be compatible with Chrome. You can go directly to the mp4 url in chrome and see the same audio-only issue. You should try a different encoder, like [Zencoder](http://zencoder.com) (paid service that I helped build) or Handbrake.

Also it looks like you swapped out the url for the video.js swf for a different swf that plays your video. That's not gonna work. You need to use the swf that's included with video.js.

Comment: Hi heff. Thanks for the quick response. In the notes it says '<!-- Unless using the CDN hosted version, update the URL to the Flash SWF'. I am intending to use the CDN hosted version so I changed the path back to the default videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf". But IE11 still showing an unsupported error. Will the encoding issue fix in IE as well do you think?

Comment: Just remove the `videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf"` line altogether. The MP4 is not playable in the browser because it does not use the h.264 video codec.

Comment: Hi guys. Just wanted to let you know that I communicated your comments to the video editor who then resupplied a new file which fixed. Thanks a lot for your help.